# How to make icon slide up with expanding panel in a Vue.js transition?

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuejs2, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a panel that expands over content from the bottom of the screen when an icon is clicked.

I'm using a Vue.js [transition](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Classes) to animate the panel sliding in from below. The panel itself animates ok but the icon pops immediately to it's final destination rather that sliding up with it.  I've demonstrated what I mean in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gavinsutherland/eywraw8t/505335/).

How can I make the icon slide up with the panel? I tried moving the icon div into the transition but that loses the animation altogether.

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
    <p>Click the orange icon to toggle the panel.</p>

    <div class="fixed-bottom">

        <!-- icon -->
        <div class="float-right iconContainer p-1"
             v-on:click.prevent="isBottomPanelExpanded = !isBottomPanelExpanded">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-arrows-alt-v fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
            </span>
        </div>  

        <!-- bottom panel -->
        <transition name="slide-fade">
            <div v-if="isBottomPanelExpanded" class="bottomPanelContainer">
                Some content ....
            </div>
        </transition>
    </div>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        isBottomPanelExpanded: false
    }
})
```

**SCSS**

```
.iconContainer {
    color: #E7722D;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;

    .fa-stack {
        vertical-align: top;
    }
}

.slide-fade-enter-active {
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.slide-fade-enter, .slide-fade-leave-to {
    transform: translateY(100px);
    opacity: 0;
}

.bottomPanelContainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #55565A;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert but manage to get it to work. Still rough around the edges but I think you can take it from here.

https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/505521/

```
<div id="app">
  <p>Click the orange icon to toggle the panel.</p>

    <div class="fixed-bottom">

    <div class="button-container">
        <!-- icon -->
    <div    v-show="isIconVisible && !isBottomPanelExpanded"
          class="float-right iconContainer p-1"
          v-on:click="isBottomPanelExpanded = !isBottomPanelExpanded">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" :class="bottomPanelIconCss">
        <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-arrows-alt-v fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
      </span>
    </div>

       <transition name="fade">
      <div  v-show="isIconVisible && isBottomPanelExpanded"
            class="float-right iconContainer p-1"
            v-on:click="isBottomPanelExpanded = !isBottomPanelExpanded">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" :class="bottomPanelIconCss">
          <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-arrows-alt-v fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
        </span>
      </div>    
      </transition>
    </div>

        <!-- bottom panel -->
        <transition name="expand">
            <div v-if="isBottomPanelExpanded" class="bottomPanelContainer">
                Some content ....
            </div>
        </transition>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this help